# ASP.NET Accessing web control inside DataList control

Tags: asp.net, datalist

Am not sure why I cannot access my Label control which was inside the Panel and the Panel is inside the DataList

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList2" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Width="100%">
<ItemTemplate>
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <!-- post details -->
            <td style="width: 60%">
                <asp:Panel ID="panelPostDetails" runat="server" CssClass="postpage_details">
                    <table border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2"><div class="postpage_header"><%# Eval("Heading") %></div></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <img src="picserver/posts/<%# Eval("ImagePath") %>/1.jpg" alt="preview" style="width: 240px;" />
                                <div id="morepictures">
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblMorePictures" runat="server" />
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div style="padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;">
                                    <div>
                                        more stuff here
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </asp:Panel>

                <asp:RoundedCornersExtender ID="RoundedCornersExtender1" runat="server" 
                    Radius="6" 
                    Corners="All" 
                    TargetControlID="panelPostDetails"></asp:RoundedCornersExtender>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>    

</ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

but when I tried using "lbl" in Page_Load, it seems it cannot find the control? can you please help me?

```
ItemDataBound and Page_Load event
---------------------------------
Panel p = DataList2.FindControl("panelPostDetails") as Panel;
Label l = p.FindControl("lblMorePictures") as Label;
l.Text = code;
```

that code returns **Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

Thanks in advance

update:

```
ItemDataBound and Page_Load event
---------------------------------
Panel p = DataList2.FindControl("panelPostDetails") as Panel;
if(p==null)
{
     System.Diagnostic.Debug.WriteLine("panel does not exist");
}
else
{
     System.Diagnostic.Debug.WriteLine("panel does exist");
}

output:
panel does not exist
```

what on earth is going on!?!

Comment: panelPostDetails is it Exists? is Panel Element in ItemTemplate?

Comment: post the markup - chances are you've missed something obvious.

Comment: @loviji - yes the panelPostDetails exists and it's in ItemTemplate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, you access controls like this at runtime by handling either the DataList's ItemCreated or ItemDataBound event. Here's a sample event handler:

```
protected void DataList2_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e) {
   if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item) {
        Label lbl = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("panelPostDetails").FindControl("lblMorePictures");
        lbl.Text = code;
   }
}
```

Wire up your the event handler like this:

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList2" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="DataList2_ItemDataBound" ...
```

Comment: the Label is inside the Panel and the Panel is inside the DataList' ItemTemplate.

Comment: sorry Peter, but still doesn't work. I have updated the code again.

Comment: Are you still trying to do this in Page_Load()? If so, that won't work. You need to do this in your DataLists's ItemDataBound event.

Comment: Sorry, I just looked at my code sample and realized that it had a bug. I've updated it. Within the ItemDataBound event handler you need to use e.Item.FindControl() **not DataList2.FindControl**.

Answer (score 0):

@Peter's code must work.

you can also try this:

```
protected void DataList2_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{
        string st= (e.Item.FindControl("lblMorePictures") as Label).Text;

}
```

and put breakpoint to wath to `st`. In my case I get a text of `lblMorePictures`.

Answer (score 0):

With my Form View I needed to add `CType` to the `FindControl`. I understand `DataList` doesn't necessarily need the `Ctype` however it is possible the Panel may need this prefix. In this case `frmDelView` is the name of my Form View. In my case the code line below is in my `PreRender` of my form. That was the only place at the time of creating the form it would return the data I needed to pass to a label on a next page of a Wizard Step page. Long story.
Note: my code is vb and not C#. It should be nearly or exactly the same.

```
 CType(frmDelView.FindControl("txtcboDAcct"), TextBox).Text
```