# dropdownlist is always null in oneditcommand in datalist

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, datalist

I'm new to asp.net trying to use datalist control.

on edititemtemplate section i have put up a dropdownlist control. It has values in it. What I want is to select a value in edit mode but when I go to event (as set in oneditcommand )  my codes cannot find dropdownlist though its in edititemtemplate. Please check my codes below

```
DropDownList ddl = e.Item.FindControl("ddlType") as DropDownList; 
ddl.Items.FindByValue((e.Item.FindControl("lblType") as Label).Text).Selected = true;
```

What I'm doing wrong?

thanks

-Navi

Answer (score 0):

take a look at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3626564/asp-net-accessing-web-control-inside-datalist-control). Typically, you access controls like this at runtime by handling either the DataList's ItemCreated or ItemDataBound event.

Comment: tried adding to databound event, still getting same error. dropdownlist control is there under edititemtemplate. not sure what wrong im doing...? :S

my codes are
     if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.EditItem) {
                DropDownList ddl = e.Item.FindControl("ddlType") as DropDownList;
                ddl.Items.FindByValue((e.Item.FindControl("lblType") as Label).Text).Selected = true;
            }