# The name 'panel1' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, web-applications

"The name 'panel1' does not exist in the current context" even if the exists how i can solve this? I tried everything, I opened a new project and just added 'panel1' then it works but this is not working in my project. Whenever I move 'panel1' out of datalist I can access panel, can i use panel inside of the datalist?

**update.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="update.aspx.cs" Inherits="update" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
    <div class="updatepanel">
        <asp:Label ID="Label9" runat="server" Text="Login Name"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Width="200px"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Label ID="Label10" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Width="200px"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Label ID="Label11" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Width="200px"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Label ID="Label12" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" Width="200px"></asp:TextBox>
</asp:Panel>
</asp:Content>
```

**update.aspx.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class update : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    string connection = "Data Source=HKAYA-L\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Sefa;Integrated Security=True";
    //string connection = "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=Sefa;Integrated Security=True";

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Panel1.visible = false; 


        SqlConnection baglanti = new SqlConnection(connection);
        string komut = string.Format("SELECT [User_ID], [Login_name], [Password], [First_name], [Last_name], [Authority_Level], [Birthday], [Salary] FROM Users");
        baglanti.Open();
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(komut, baglanti);
        SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
        DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
        dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);
        DataList2.DataSource = dataSet;
        DataList2.DataBind();
        baglanti.Close();


    }
}
```

i actually try everything but still does'nt working.

Comment: You haven't shown your DataList. Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/3626683/284240

Comment: It helps but i can reach panel1 in the DataList2_ItemDataBound. How can i reach in the Page_Load? For example i wanna set visiblity from page load. Also the reason for not showing the datalist is writing too much code just showing the panel definition.

Comment: Why you want to set it Visible=False always? You could make it invisible by default(in the markup) and make it visible in an event handler.

Comment: yes i can do like that but i wanna reach panel maybe button click event the page_load was just example.

Comment: You also need to check the code-behind name to make sure the "Inherits" attribute in the "<%@ Page %>" directive matches the class name in the code-behind file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though the provided code is not complete, it seems the error "The name 'panel1' does not exist in the current context" is a visual studio issue and might disappear after exiting VS and reopening the project.

Normally, access to template controls is available in DataList.ItemDataBound event. AFAIK, there is no direct access to controls in templates, so in order to access these controls in other events e.g. page_load or button_click, we should write a function to deep search in all datalist controls:

```
Control GetControlByID(Control RootControl, string ID)
{
if (RootControl == null | string.IsNullOrEmpty(ID))
    return null;
    if (RootControl.ID == ID)
        return RootControl;
    foreach (Control ctl in RootControl.Controls)
    {
        if (ctl.ID == ID)
            return ctl;
        else
        {
            Control ctlx = GetControlByID(ctl, ID);
            if (ctlx != null)
                return ctlx;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Consider the following example with some panels are added just for demo:

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" RepeatColumns="4" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" OnItemCommand="DataList1_ItemCommand" OnItemDataBound="DataList1_ItemDataBound">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <asp:Panel ID="HeaderPanel" runat="server">
            <asp:Label ID="HeaderLabel" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
        </asp:Panel>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        <asp:Panel ID="FooterPanel" runat="server">
            <asp:Label ID="FooterLabel" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
        </asp:Panel>
    </FooterTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Panel ID="ItemPanel" runat="server">
            <asp:Label ID="ItemLabel" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
            ProductID:
            <asp:Label ID="ProductIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ProductID") %>' />
            <br />
            ProductName:
            <asp:Label ID="ProductNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ProductName") %>' />
            <br />
            <asp:Button ID="ItemButton" runat="server" Text="Select" CommandName="select" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ProductName") %>' />
        </asp:Panel>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="Wheat" />
    <FooterStyle BackColor="Wheat" />
    <SelectedItemStyle BackColor="WhiteSmoke" />
</asp:DataList>

<div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row; gap: 10px; border: solid; margin: 10px; padding: 5px; width: fit-content;">
    <asp:Label ID="labelTBH" runat="server">Text:</asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxHeader" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="Btn_SetHeaderText" runat="server" Text="Set as Header Text" OnClick="Btn_SetHeaderText_Click" />
    <asp:Button ID="Btn_SetFooterText" runat="server" Text="Set as Footer Text" OnClick="Btn_SetFooterText_Click" />
</div>
```

**To initialize the text of a label inside a panel in the header template:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        Panel panel = (Panel)GetControlByID(DataList1, "HeaderPanel");
        Label lbl = (Label)panel.FindControl("HeaderLabel");
        // first find panel in header template and then find label in panel
        lbl.Text = "Initial Header Text";
    }
}
```

**To set the text of a label inside the header-template/footer-template by button click :**

```
protected void Btn_SetHeaderText_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label lbl = (Label)GetControlByID(DataList1, "HeaderLabel");
    // find label directly
    lbl.Text = TextBoxHeader.Text;
}

protected void Btn_SetFooterText_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label lbl = (Label)GetControlByID(DataList1, "FooterLabel");
    lbl.Text = TextBoxHeader.Text;
}
```

**To count number of items in datalist and write it in the label inside footer-template:**

```
int Items_Count = 0;
protected void DataList1_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.Item.ItemType)
    {
        case ListItemType.Item:
        case ListItemType.AlternatingItem:
            Items_Count++;
            break;
        case ListItemType.Footer:
            Label Flbl = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("FooterLabel");
            Flbl.Text = $"Items Count = {Items_Count}";
            break;
    }
}
```